# Parallelcoordinates in R-highcharter R

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I want to know how to use the `highcharter`-package to create parallelplots. I already found an implementation in the `MASS`-package, but this doesn't look nice. It results in

```
d <- iris[,1:4]
MASS::parcoord(d)
```

[image]

Since I want to use the plot in ShinyApps, I need a nicer visualization. I prefer highcharts, so I want to use the `highcharter`-package. Under https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples//highcharts/demo/parallel-coordinates/ we can find a demo of how to put in the data into highcharts, but I don't know how to set up the `hchart`-function correctly. I think it should be something like

```
hc <- highcharter::hchart(chart = list(type="spline",parallelCoordinates=TRUE) ...
```

Some help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(highcharter)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

series_lst <- 
  iris %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  asplit(1) %>% 
  imap(~list(
    name = paste("observation", .y),
    data = as.numeric(.x[1:4]),
    color = "steelblue"
  ))

hc <- 
  highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(parallelCoordinates = TRUE, type = "spline") %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = names(iris)[1:4]) %>% 
  hc_add_series_list(series_lst)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to color the yAxis-labels?
I tried `hc %>% hc_yAxis(labels=list(style=list(color="red")))`, which only makes the first Sepal.Length labels red. I also found the `hc_yAxis_multiples`, but this also doesn't help. Using `hc %>% hc_yAxis_multiples(labels=rep(list(style=list(color="red")),4))` also only makes the first one red.

Comment: I created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67868378/color-yaxis-in-parallelplot-in-r-highcharter as followup to this one.